# Ignoring nodes with duplicate data

Tags: xslt

In the below xml, I would like to ignore the third node `<Data1>12347</Data1>` because I have to account for only the first unique occurrence of `refCode`. Since the first node value and third node value of refCode is 112233, I want to ignore the third node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Example>
    <Row>
        <Data1>12345</Data1>
        <Data2>
            <DataRef>
                <RefName>refCode</RefName>
                <RefValue>112233</RefValue>
            </DataRef>
            <DataRef>
                <RefName>SKU</RefName>
                <RefValue>444-1112</RefValue>
            </DataRef>
        </Data2>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Data1>12346</Data1>
        <Data2>
            <DataRef>
                <RefName>refCode</RefName>
                <RefValue>325325</RefValue>
            </DataRef>          
            <DataRef>
                <RefName>SKU</RefName>
                <RefValue>444-1113</RefValue>
            </DataRef>
        </Data2>            
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Data1>12347</Data1>
        <Data2>
            <DataRef>
                <RefName>refCode</RefName>
                <RefValue>112233</RefValue>
            </DataRef>          
            <DataRef>
                <RefName>SKU</RefName>
                <RefValue>444-1114</RefValue>
            </DataRef>
        </Data2>            
    </Row>  
</Example>
```

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

For XSLT-1.0 use an XSLT with a distinct value principle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="distinct" match="Row" use="Data2/DataRef/RefValue" />

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- matches unique Row elements -->
  <xsl:template match="Row[generate-id(key('distinct',Data2/DataRef/RefValue)) = generate-id()]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ignores doublettes -->
  <xsl:template match="Row" />      

</xsl:stylesheet>
```